# exception.getMessage() output with class name

Tags: java, exception

I'm trying to fix an issue, in my application I have this code

```
try {
  object1.method1();
} catch(Exception ex) {
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(nulll, "Error: "+ex.getMessage());
}
```

and the object1 would do something like that:

```
public void method1() {
   //some code...
   throw new RuntimeException("Cannot move file");
}
```

I get a messsage in my option pane like this:
`Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot move file`

but I used `getMessage` and not `toString` method, so the name of the class shouldn´t appear, right?

What I am doing wrong?
I already tryied with a lot of exceptions, even `Exception` itself. I'm looking to solve this no without the need to implement my own `Exception` subclass

**PROBLEM SOLVED - thank you all!**

The try and catch were actually being called in **get()** method from SwingWorker which constructs an `ExecutionException` with my exception thrown from **doInBackground()**
I fixed doing this:

```
@Override
protected void done() {
    try {
        Object u = (Object) get();
        //do whatever u want
    } catch(ExecutionException ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error: "+ex.getCause().getMessage());
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error: "+ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds odd - can you reproduce this in a short but complete program?

Comment: Can you add `e.printStackTrace()` as well in `catch`? It looks like @dacwe is right.

Comment: Looking at the stack trace I can see that the problem might be the Swing Worker.......the try { } is actually calling get() from swing worker method done() and the exception is thrown in doInBackGround

Comment: It is [questionable whether you should report the message text of an exception in the GUI at all](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7320080/should-you-report-the-message-text-of-exceptions).

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I think you are wrapping your exception in another exception (which isn't in your code above). If you try out this code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        throw new RuntimeException("Cannot move file");
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error: " + ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

...you will see a popup that says exactly what you want.

---

However, to solve your problem (the wrapped exception) you need get to the "root" exception with the "correct" message. To do this you need to create a own recursive method `getRootCause`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        throw new Exception(new RuntimeException("Cannot move file"));
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                                      "Error: " + getRootCause(ex).getMessage());
    }
}

public static Throwable getRootCause(Throwable throwable) {
    if (throwable.getCause() != null)
        return getRootCause(throwable.getCause());

    return throwable;
}
```

*Note: Unwrapping exceptions like this however, sort of breaks the abstractions. I encourage you to find out why the exception is wrapped and ask yourself if it makes sense.*

Comment: Your getRootCause method is not protected against infinite recursion.

Comment: @Perception, Unless the throwable has itself as its cause or you have some other super weird cyclic chain of causes you shouldn't need to worry about it.

Comment: @aioobe - True, those are the primary reasons to check. But it's not as rare an occurrence as you might think.

Comment: I disagree. I've *never* run across such situation. Actually, not even the designers of the `Throwable`-class takes that scenario into account considering the `printStackTrace` method.

Comment: Use org.apache.commons.lang3.exception.ExceptionUtils.getRootCause() instead of rolling your own

Answer (score 8):

My guess is that you've got something in `method1` which wraps one exception in another, and uses the `toString()` of the nested exception as the message of the wrapper. I suggest you take a copy of your project, and remove as much as you can while keeping the problem, until you've got a short but complete program which demonstrates it - at which point either it'll be clear what's going on, or we'll be in a better position to help fix it.

Here's a short but complete program which demonstrates `RuntimeException.getMessage()` behaving correctly:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            failingMethod();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }       

    private static void failingMethod() {
        throw new RuntimeException("Just the message");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Error: Just the message
```