# How to get message from Exception?

Tags: android

Following is my piece of code:\

```
public void LoadProjectFile(String Filename) throws Exception
{
  //  m_Renderer.m_Project=new Project();
   refresh_project();
    m_Renderer.m_SelectedProjectPath =  Filename;

    try {
        m_Renderer.m_Project.load_file(Filename);

    }
    catch (Exception e)

    {
        //Exception a = e.getMessage();
        String a= e.getMessage();

        throw new Exception(a);
    }

    //AppFuncs.m_GisProject=m_Renderer.m_Project;

}



        try
        {

            Map.this.mGLView.LoadProjectFile(AppFuncs.g_path);
             Map.this.mGLView.requestRender();
    }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            br=1;
             b=e.getMessage();
        }
```

Load project file throws an exception which i recieve in Map class. `This exception contains message: Java.lang.exception: java.lang.exception: file not found.`

I want to show only `"File not found"` message. so how should i get this message out from an exception?

Comment: Have a look at this, its exactly what you looking for 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9017820/exception-getmessage-output-without-class-name

Answer (score 0):

Catch all types of exceptions instead of base Exception:

```
try {
    m_Renderer.m_Project.load_file(Filename);

}
catch (FileNotFoundException e)
{
    String a= "File not found"
    throw new Exception(a);
}
catch (SomeOhterException e){ 
    String a= "Some other message"
    throw new Exception(a);
}
//at the end, but it shouldn't be necessary 
catch (Exception e){ 
    String a= "Something happend we don't know what"
    throw new Exception(a);
}
```

Shortly: Use different class for different exception to show correct information rahter than using exception message.

Comment: i have cathed these exception in loadproject file exception

Comment: @MuneemHabib I don't understand. You are not catching it in code snippet you provided. If you are catching them inside `m_Renderer.m_Project.load_file()` and throwing Exception instead you shouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

Just catch the `FileNotFoundException` instead of an `Exception`.

For example:

```
try {
      //whatever
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
      System.out.println("File not found");
}
```