# Exception methods e.getMessage() and e.getLocalizedMessage() are showing package

Tags: java, exception

I'm adding Exception handling to my Java application and don't understand why in some cases the String returned by *Exception* methods `e.getMessage()` or `e.getLocalizedMessage()` includes the package of my custom Exception class.

This is how I have it configured:

**MyCustomException:**

```
package project.be.exception;

public class MyCustomException extends Exception{
 public MyCustomException() {

}

public MyCustomException(String arg0) {
    super(arg0);

}

public MyCustomException(Throwable arg0) {
    super(arg0);

}

public MyCustomException(String arg0, Throwable arg1) {
    super(arg0, arg1);

}

public MyCustomException(String arg0, Throwable arg1, boolean arg2, boolean arg3) {
    super(arg0, arg1, arg2, arg3);

}
}
```

**MyServiceCaller:**

```
public class MyServiceCaller implements HISException DefaultRESTService<DefaultModel>{


    public DefaultResponse get(Service_Api service, Object caller, Object param) throws MyCustomException {

        try{
         ...
        } catch (Exception e){
           throw new MyCustomException ("Hello message exception");
        }

        }
}
```

**MyBussinessClass:**

```
...
try{
 new MyServiceCaller().get(service, param1, param2);
} catch(MyCustomException e){
   System.out.println(e.getLocalizedMessage());
}
...
```

**Console output:**

```
project.be.exception: Hello message exception
```

I want to print only the message without previous the package. Any suggestion?

***Edit1:***

The output is the same using Exception.getMessage(), thus I discard possible duplication with question:
[Difference between e.getMessage() and e.getLocalizedMessage()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24988491)

**SOLUTION:**

As [isaac](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3991350/isaac) mentioned, I'm wraping the thrown exception in another and by this reason `e.getMessage()` and `e.getLocalizedMessage()` shows the package.

In my case solve the output was easy calling `e.getCause().getMessage()` instead of `e.getMessage()` and `e.getLocalizedMessage()`.

Comment: @devpuh the issue it identical with e.getMessage()

Comment: The code for the constructor `MyCustomException` is missing. Also do you override `getMessage()` or `getLocalizedMessage()`?

Comment: Why not use a logger instead of sysout ? For instance, [java.util.logging](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/logging/package-summary.html) .

Comment: @devpuh getMessage() or getLocalizedMessage() aren't overrided

Comment: You may be facing the issue described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9017820/exception-getmessage-output-with-class-name), i.e. you're somehow, inadvertently, wrapping the thrown exception in another, especially since you say it only happens "sometimes". I think it'd helpful if you could provide a working and a non-working example.

Comment: @MickaëlB using logger (java.util.logging) the issue is exactly the same

Comment: @isaac you're right. I'm wrapping the thrown exception in another.

Comment: I don't think the solution you mentionned works in all cases because an exception can have more than one cause....

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use a logging system instead of using the Java SysOut : `System.out.println(...)`. With a logging system, you can define the format of your logs.

**Here's an example with [`java.util.logging`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/logging/package-summary.html)** :

You can define your own logging format. Here's an example of [`Formatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/logging/Formatter.html) that will only display the message of any Exception :

```
public class MyFormatter extends Formatter {

    public String format(LogRecord record) {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append(formatMessage(record));
        builder.append("\n");
        return builder.toString();
    }
}
```

Then you can use it as following :

```
public class MyClass {

    // Your logger
    private static Logger logger ;

    // Static initialization block for the logger
    static {
        logger = Logger.getLogger("MyClass");
        try {
            ConsoleHandler handler = new ConsoleHandler();
            handler.setFormatter(new MyFormatter());
            logger.addHandler(handler);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Failed to initialize Handler", e);
        }
    }

    //...
}
```

Please note that's not proper way to configure your logging system. The point is to show how it works. In a real application, you can use system properties, configuration files, etc...

In order to configure your logger correctly, there're several solutions. Take a look to this Stack overflow question :

- [How do I get java logging output to appear on a single line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194765/how-do-i-get-java-logging-output-to-appear-on-a-single-line)

I hope this will help you.

Comment: I've using java.util.logging in my application but I thought that was more clear SysOut for the question.  Thanks for the recommendation.